# Replace a base class with a concrete implementation C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, oop

I have the following abstract class and interface:

```
public interface ITypedEntity{
    TypedEntity Type { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TypedEntity:INamedEntity{
    public abstract int Id{get;set;}
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But when i try to create a class that implements ITypedEntity and has a concrecte implementation of TypedEntity i get the following error

```
 Magazine does not implement interface member ITypedEntity.Type. Magazine.Type cannot implement 'ITypedEntity.Type' because it does not have the matching return type of 'TypedEntity'
```

The code for my concrecte implementation is below

```
public class Magazine:INamedEntity,ITypedEntity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public MagazineType Type { get; set; }
}
public class MagazineType : TypedEntity
{
    override public int Id { get; set; }
    override public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I think i understand what is happening but i don't know why because MagazineType is a TypedEntity.

Thanks.

**Update 1**
I have to mention that i want to use this classes with EF CodeFirst and i want to have a different table for each of the classes that implement ITypedEntity.

Comment: MagazineType is TypedEntity but TypedEntity isn't a MagazineType. Maybe you can define your interface like `ITypedEntity Type { get; set; }`

Comment: But code having a reference to a `Magazine` stored in a variable of type `ITypedEntity` might try to store something that *isn't* a `MagazineType` into the `Type` property.

Comment: change the return type of `Magazine.Type` to `EntityType`. It can still be an instance of `MagazineType` but the signature must match to satify the interface implmentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter that `MagazineType` is a `TypedEntity`. Imagine you have another `ITypedEntity` implementation, `NewspaperType`. The contract of the ITypedEntity interface states you must be able to do:

```
ITypedEntity magazine = new Magazine();
magazine.Type = new NewspaperType();
```

However this contradicts your code, in which `Magazine.Type` doesn't accept other subtypes of `ITypedEntity`. (I believe your code would be valid if the property only had a getter though.)

A solution would be using generics:

```
interface ITypedEntity<TType> where TType : TypedEntity
{
    TType Type { get; set; }
}

class Magazine : ITypedEntity<MagazineType>
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to change the MagazineType to TypedEntity

```
public class Magazine:INamedEntity,ITypedEntity
{
public int Id {get;set;}
[MaxLength(250)]
public string Name {get;set;}
public TypedEntity Type { get; set; }
}
```

but when you create object of Magazine then you can assign a derived type to it

```
var magazine = new Magazine { Type = new MagazineType() }
```

Comment: I know that works, but the problem is that this are some models that i intend to use with EF CodeFirst and i'm not really sure how that will work, because i want to have a different table for each class concrect implementation of TypedEntity

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you have to add an [`explicit` implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of `ITypedEntity.Type`:

```
public class Magazine:INamedEntity,ITypedEntity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public MagazineType Type { get; set; }

    TypedEntity ITypedEntity.Type 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Type;
        } 
        set 
        {
            this.Type = value as MagazineType; // or throw an exception if value
                                               // is not a MagazineType 
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Magazine mag = new Magazine();
mag.Type                 \\ points to `public MagazineType Type { get; set; }`
((ITypedEntity)mag).Type \\ point to `TypedEntity ITypedEntity.Type`
```